# Explicit type casting of object to int *

Tags: c++

What is the output of the following c++ code ?

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
class IndiaBix
{
    int x, y; 
    public:
    IndiaBix(int xx)
    {
        x = ++xx;
    } 
    ~IndiaBix()
    {
        cout<< x - 1 << " ";
    }
    void Display()
    {
        cout<< --x + 1 << " ";
    } 
};
int main()
{
    IndiaBix objBix(5);
    objBix.Display();
    int *p = (int*) &objBix;
    *p = 40;
    objBix.Display();
    return 0; 
}
```

I did n't understand the following line ::

```
 int *p = (int*) &objBix;//Explicit type cast of a class object to integer pointer type
```

Comment: @Andrey: I was about to ask the same, but looking at ecatmur's answer I can see this being a valid question. The muddy waters between UD and OK are a little hard to test with "just running it and see".

Comment: @honk: The 1st OP's question is "What is the output"

Comment: It's funny how people use these weird features, and then go on to complain C++ is a minefield...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to cast an object pointer (of a standard-layout type) to a pointer to its first member. This is because it is guaranteed that the first member of a standard-layout object has the same address as the overall object:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 9.2 Class members [class.mem]
>
> 20 - A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its
>   initial member (or if that member is a bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

Thus `int *p = (int*) &objBix;` is a pointer to `objBix.x`, since `objBix` is standard-layout; both its data members `x` and `y` are `private`, and the class has no `virtual` methods or base classes.

Comment: Would it be advised to use `size_t` if one were needing to do this?

Comment: Beware: this is guaranteed only for *standard layout* types. Add a virtual function and you will be in undefined behavior land.

Comment: Only if the type is *standard-layout*.

Comment: @Aesthete I don't see how `size_t` is relevant.

Comment: This violates class visibilty too. x and y are both private.

Comment: It's not relevant, sorry. Removing my comment.  @ecatmur