# What does this mean *((int*)(&val) +1)

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to understand this line of code. Can someone help me? Is it saving the result in the variable val or in the address of the variable val?

```
*((int*)(&val) +1)= A*(y) + (B - C)
```

Thank you

Comment: How are `val`, `y`, `A`, `B`, and `C` are declared?

Comment: Note that you should avoid C-style casts in C++. Or is this code actually C and not C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&val` take the address of `val`
`(int*)(&val)` consider this address as a pointer to `int`
`(int*)(&val) +1` increment this address by 1 (times `sizeof(int)`)
`*((int*)(&val) +1) = ...` assign the right hand side value at this incremented address

Answer (score 3):

It is interpreting `val` as if it was an array of integers, and storing the result of the right hand expression in its second element. To understand exactly the point of it all you should provide some more context (my guess: is it manipulating the raw content of `double` values?)

Notice that, depending on the type of `val`, this may be undefined behavior due to strict aliasing rules.

Answer (score 2):

Divide expression `*((int*)(&val) +1)` into smaller ones to understand it:

1. take address of `val` (`&val)` and treat it as a pointer to an int `(int *)`
2. add 1 `+1` to this pointer which means 'move pointer to next int' as it was an array of ints.
3. finaly by combining `*` and `=` apply right hand side expression to `int` pointed by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I hope others have answered your question. Adding to what others have said, the same code can be written as follows:

```
(int*)(&val)[1]= A*(y) + (B - C)
```

where (int*) will type cast &val as an implicit pointer to an integer which points to the address of val and [1] indicates the first integer location ahead of the location where val is stored.

This is how arrays are interpreted. Say you have an array

```
int a[10];
```

For this array, **'a'** is a pointer which points to the base address ( address of the element a[0] ), and **a[i]** is nothing but ***(a+i)**, i.e. the element which is i locations ahead of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

## This is not correct code and you should never use it

Imagine this class:

```
class A {
    int number = 10;
    public:
    void print(){ std::cout << number; }
};
```

The `int number` is private for the access not the use!

So how can we access this private `int`.

Simply:

```
A obj;
*( (int*) ( &obj ) ) = 100;
obj.print();
```

**output**

100

---

[demo](http://cpp.sh/7lfsh)

Now if you would have more than one data then how to access?

by this syntax:
`*((int*)(&val) +1)`

It says:
find the address of the first data,
one index go ahead,
cast it to the `int*`,
then dereference it,
then initialize it

Comment: This "simple" access is not allowed by C++ and results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: I am not kidding you. Are you familiar with undefined behaviour?

Comment: P.S.: One of the devious things about UB is precisely that it *may* sometimes work, or appear to work. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: If you know what UB means, then what's the purpose of your demo?

Comment: Where is my code has the **undefined behavior**, please tell me exactly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134299/discussion-between-k-five-and-christian-hackl).

Comment: Instead of paying attention to the code, you just know to **down vote** me. Of course this is not a actual code and **nobody** uses it. I just want to show this syntax work. That's it. I know what the undefined behavior is. [prove](https://github.com/k-five/1000_examples_with_cpp)

Comment: Upon closer consideration, I've decided to remove by downvote, because your class `A` is a **standard-layout class**, so C++ actually does allow this. However, I do still have the feeling that you are not aware of how barely it does so; for example, it **would be UB if you added a `public` data field**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093319/why-does-c-allow-private-members-to-be-modified-using-this-approach. I am also not convinced that you really understand what UB is, because one successful program execution obviously doesn't prove something to be correct C++.

Comment: I am also very unhappy with the way you present this horrible technique to a beginner. You could at least have used a `reinterpret_cast` in your example, and explained how dangerous it is.

Comment: @ChristianHackl dear. **It is not a actual code**, **NOT NOT NOT** I want to show that this syntax woks. **I never say that is correct** **NEVER**

Comment: *"So how can we access this private int. Simply: [...]"* does not exactly sound like *"This is not correct code and you should never use it"*.

Comment: Instead of **down vote** me it would be better, that yourself. would edit my code I put this note.

Comment: I only edit answers for formatting or spelling fixes. Possibly changing the meaning of an answer would be rude and/or not even allowed by Stack Overflow.

Comment: **first** I you 100% sure. then it is better to edit. and it is not rude if you 100% suer. **second** Edit my code **everywhere** you see it later forever. I will happy with that

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. It would completely defeat the purpose of the reputation system.

Comment: But if I was 100% sure about adding a **correct** sentence, I would do it. **even for your code** :)